# Query against two integer columns take an absurd amount of time

Tags: mysql, sql, database-indexes

I have a query that gets generated (by Django) like this:

```
SELECT `geo_ip`.`id`, `geo_ip`.`start_ip`,
       `geo_ip`.`end_ip`, `geo_ip`.`start`,
       `geo_ip`.`end`, `geo_ip`.`cc`, `geo_ip`.`cn`
FROM `geo_ip`
WHERE (`geo_ip`.`start` <= 2084738290 AND `geo_ip`.`end` >= 2084738290 )
LIMIT 1
```

It queries a GeoLocating table with 134189 entries in it. Each query takes >100ms to perform when indexes are added, which makes it unusable for more than one-off things. I'm going to cache the response so I only have to do the IP lookup once, but I'm curious if I'm missing some obvious way of making it a magnitude faster. My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `geo_ip` (
  `start_ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `end_ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `start` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `end` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cc` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `cn` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134190 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Creating an index on both columns like so:

```
ALTER TABLE geo_ip ADD INDEX (start, end);
```

Gives the following explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT geo_ip.id, geo_ip.start_ip, geo_ip.end_ip,
               geo_ip.start, geo_ip.end, geo_ip.cc, geo_ip.cn
FROM geo_ip
WHERE (geo_ip.end >= 2084738290 AND geo_ip.start < 2084738290)
LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_ip | range | start         | start | 8       | NULL | 67005 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

It takes well over 100ms to complete selects:

```
SELECT geo_ip.id, geo_ip.start_ip, geo_ip.end_ip,
       geo_ip.start, geo_ip.end, geo_ip.cc,
       geo_ip.cn
FROM geo_ip
WHERE (geo_ip.end >= 2084738290 and geo_ip.start < 2084738290)
LIMIT 1;
+-------+--------------+----------------+------------+------------+----+-----------+
| id    | start_ip     | end_ip         | start      | end        | cc | cn        |
+-------+--------------+----------------+------------+------------+----+-----------+
| 51725 | 124.66.128.0 | 124.66.159.255 | 2084732928 | 2084741119 | SG | Singapore |
+-------+--------------+----------------+------------+------------+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.18 sec)
```

Is more expensive than having a single individual index:

```
ALTER TABLE geo_ip ADD INDEX (`start`);
ALTER TABLE geo_ip ADD INDEX (`end`);
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_ip | range | start,end     | start | 8       | NULL | 68017 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

It takes around 100ms to complete these requests:

```
SELECT geo_ip.id, geo_ip.start_ip, geo_ip.end_ip, geo_ip.start, geo_ip.end, geo_ip.cc, geo_ip.cn FROM geo_ip
WHERE (geo_ip.end >= 2084738290 AND geo_ip.start < 2084738290) limit 1;
+-------+--------------+----------------+------------+------------+----+-----------+
| id    | start_ip     | end_ip         | start      | end        | cc | cn        |
+-------+--------------+----------------+------------+------------+----+-----------+
| 51725 | 124.66.128.0 | 124.66.159.255 | 2084732928 | 2084741119 | SG | Singapore |
+-------+--------------+----------------+------------+------------+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)
```

But both of these methods take way too long, is it possible to do anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

Time is always consumed in the "where" clause.

And because you are working on two different fields with "lower than" or "greater than", it has to read a lot of indexes to find out which record is the one you want.

I should have done my table this way :

```
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+----+-----------+
| id    | type  | ip             | geo        | cc | cn        |
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+----+-----------+
| 51725 | start | 124.66.159.255 | 2084732928 | SG | Singapore |
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+----+-----------+
| 51726 | end   | 124.66.159.255 | 2084732928 | SG | Singapore |
+-------+-------+----------------+------------+----+-----------+
```

so that I can select this :

```
select * from table where geo between '2084732927' and '2084732928'
```

with an index on geo.
Should be much, much faster. But sorry, I have no time to try.